# Qt sql query failed

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qtsql

```
query->prepare("INSERT INTO businessweek (id, source, date, headline, body) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
query->bindValue(1, "source");
query->bindValue(2, "date");
query->bindValue(3, "headline");
query->bindValue(4, "body");

if (query->exec()) {
    tt << "Query success";
} else {
    qDebug() << db.lastError();
    return;
}
```

I'm using QMYSQL. And the error is

```
 QSqlError(-1, "", "")
```

But

```
query->exec("INSERT INTO businessweek (id, source, date, headline, body) VALUES (NULL, 'google', 'may 0, 23', 'head', 'fjsdflksjdlkfdsjlfkjd');")
```

is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to guess the problem. But one thing I could imagine and that definitely is wrong with your code is that field numbering for `bindValue` starts at 0 (see [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#bindValue-2)).

Thus, I would suggest to try

```
query->prepare("INSERT INTO businessweek (id, source, date, headline, body) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
query->bindValue(0, "source");
query->bindValue(1, "date");
query->bindValue(2, "headline");
query->bindValue(3, "body");

if (query->exec()) {
    tt << "Query success";
} else {
    qDebug() << db.lastError();
    return;
}
```